# show or hide a button based on user role in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, acl

I have two roles in my web app 1-employee 2-scrum master i want to hide some buttons for the normal employee and only show it for the scrum master in the same view is there any simple way to do it...thanks in advance

Comment: Use [gates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#gates) (or policies).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about laravel's Standard Method but You have to use If Condition anyways! So, Here is the Quick Solution that I use.

```
@if(Auth::user()->user_role == "role")
    // Show Button <button>...</button>
@endif
```

This is what I do when I have to show some information to users having specific roles and hide from other users.

Let me know if Helps!

Comment: What if i use a provider and pass auth user role in the boot function, and in view i use that variable? For example i am using a navigation bar and it is used in every view. Would that be better or just doing if else

Comment: @Wang'lPakhrin I had a similar situation where I had to show features based on user's plan. What I did is I attached Subscriptions and Features tables with one pivot table (Many to many relationship) and it works like a charm! I can even manage features of specific user from my admin panel!